# npm install breaks after upgrading angular-cli from version 4 to 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to convert one of my **Angular4** project to **Angular7**. These are the steps i followed to convert my **Angular4** project to **Angular7**.

1. I uninstalled older version of **angular-cli**
2. I installed a newer updated version of **angular-cli**
3. Now, When I try to do `npm install` it gave me the error as stated below.

**Please correct me if i am not following the correct steps to upgrade to Angular7**

```
compiler_cli_1.readConfiguration is not a function
TypeError: compiler_cli_1.readConfiguration is not a function
at AngularCompilerPlugin._setupOptions (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:91:39)
at new AngularCompilerPlugin (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:52:14)
at _createAotPlugin (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:41:12)
at Object.getNonAotConfig (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:47:19)
at BrowserBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:84:37)
at DevServerBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:111:46)
at MergeMapSubscriber.check_port_1.checkPort.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:38:40)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at TapSubscriber._next (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
at InnerSubscriber._next (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
at ForkJoinSubscriber.notifyComplete (V:\LamdaAngular\livepinangularwebsite\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\observable\forkJoin.js:82:25)
```

Comment: Please add the code causing the problem.

Comment: Your question is being down voted because there is not enough information for us to really help. There is one issue I found that was related and suggested using a newer version of the Angular CLI. You can find that here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8287

Comment: i have updated my question with details of problem

Answer (score 8):

This will surely fix this `ng update @angular/compiler-cli --force`  and this `ng update @angular/cli --force`

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me......

```
ng update @angular/compiler-cli --force
ng update @angular/cli --force
npm audit fix
npm start
```